# How to create and save a predefined checklist collection for users and set up the associations between four models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a small project to gain more skill in Ruby an RoR development.

Now I got stuck and it drives me crazy. I looked on Stack Overflow and Google for the answer, but I think I'm asking the wrong questions.

**The idea:**

- A user can create and login to his account
- The user can create one dashboard with following fields

  - Title
  - Description
- Each dashboard contains four predefined checklists (like categories)

  - These checklists are displaying a progress of the user that is defined by tasks
  - Every checklist contains a collection predefined of tasks (checkboxes)
- The tasks are like to-dos that the user has to complete, so I can updated the progress on the checklist (x of y tasks are complete. xy% done)

  - Its the same set of checkboxes for every user

**The problem:**

1. My problem is now, how do I create and save the predefined set of tasks for each user,  on the creation of the dashboard, with the right associations between the *user* and *checklist* model
2. Are my associations between the four models right? Is there another or better way to set this up?

**Status-Quo:**

These are associations between the models and the schema. The Rails version is 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.2.3. The app is running in a docker container with postgres.

**user.rb**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :dashboards, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :tasks, :through => :checklists #Is this right?
      has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy

      validates_length_of :dashboards, :maximum => 1

      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :omniauthable, :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable
    end
```

**dashboard.rb**

```
class Dashboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates                 :user_id, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of   :title
  validates_length_of       :description, maximum: 300
end
```

**task.rb**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :checklist
  belongs_to :user

  validates                 :user_id, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of   :title
  validates_length_of       :description, maximum: 300
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160514200622) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "checklists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end

  create_table "dashboards", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "dashboards", ["user_id"], name: "index_dashboards_on_user_id", using: :btree


  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.boolean  "completed"
    t.integer  "checklist_id"
  end

  add_index "tasks", ["checklist_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_checklist_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: ""
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.integer  "invited_by_id"
    t.string   "invited_by_type"
    t.integer  "invitations_count",      default: 0
  end

  add_foreign_key "dashboards", "users"
  add_foreign_key "identities", "users"
  add_foreign_key "tasks", "checklists"
end
```

I will appreciate your help with my problem.

Comment: There is a little mistake.

Ignore the following part from the task.rb

 `validates                 :user_id, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of   :title
  validates_length_of       :description, maximum: 300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modeling is a bit off:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checklists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tasks, through: :checklists
end

class Checklist
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
end

class Task
  belongs_to :checklist
  has_one :user, through: :checklist
end
```

Here checklist works as a join model that allows the indirect relationships between User and Task.

Not that when using the `through` option you actually have to declare the relationship that it should go through:

```
# has_many :checklists
has_many :tasks, through: :checklists # Error!
```

When setting up the relationship back to user from task you want to use `has_one` and not `belongs_to`.

```
class Task
  belongs_to :checklist
  has_one :user, through: :checklist # points to checklists.user_id
end
```

and not `belongs_to :user` as you don't want to have the `user_id` column in two places as ActiveRecord will not keep `tasks.user_id` up to date! 
Fortunately you have not created a `tasks.user_id` column anyways.

Comment: Hey @max ,
thank you very much. 

So I have to create join table checklists with a task_id and user_id?

`class CreateAssembliesPartsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users_tasks, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :taks_id
    end

    add_index :users_tasks, :user_id
    add_index :users_tasks, :task_id
  end
end`

Comment: Why has the task just one user? Every user should have the same predefined tasks. 

User has a Dashboard "Cardio"
This dashboard contains four checklists with eacht 10 predefined tasks (checkboxes)

Comment: Because if a single task belonged to many users than if one user checks off the task then it becomes checked off for all users...

Comment: If you wan't to have predefined tasks you would do it either through something like a Service Object which creates the tasks for a new user.

Comment: If you need the presets to be user editedable you need a much more complex setup where the "preset tasks" and "user assigned tasks" are stored on different tables.

Comment: well that makes more then just sense :)

If __has_one :user, through: :checklist__ points to checklists.user_id then I need the foreignkey user_id in checklists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112053/discussion-between-max-and-aleksandar-basara).